How to make emacs use my tab width for C-M-\?
My ~/.xemacs consists of the single line
(setq-default tab-width 4) 

However, emacs doesn't correctly auto indent when i write code.
When i press return after a line the cursor jumps to the column in which my line started (as i expect it to do).
But after opening a brace the indentation of the next line is only 2 instead of 4. This remains the case if i move the cursor onto this line and press TAB.
Also, the indentation command C-M-\ reformats a region with indents of size 2.
How can i tell emacs to use the tab width i specified for indentations?

Different modes uses different variables for indentation. I think that variables like indent-offset is controlling the indentation.Which mode are you using?

I didn't explicitly set any mode, but i use emacs mainly for coding (C++,  python) or for editing XML files. If i add "(setq indent-offset 4)" in my ~/.emacs the behaviour is still the same.

@user1479670 Emacs normally sets the mode based on the buffer's file suffix. tab-width will only have an effect if the current mode's indentation uses tabs. There is no global indent-offset, but there are mode-specific ones.
